# How to add $1.25 to any shipping method

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, extrafee

I have multiwarehouse concept in my site. So I want to add 1.25 to shipping charge. I wrote the functionality so its adding 1.25 depends upon how much products I have added from warehouse.Suppose I have added three products from three warehouse so its adding 3.75(1.25+1.25+1.25= 3.75). But I want 1.25 if we add any products from multiple warehouse.

Comment: Which shipping method?

Comment: Fedex Shipping Method